# Is there a limit to the amount of times I can start an Automation via SOAP API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I was able to successfully run this  call once, but I'm not seeing it actually run in SFMC again after that.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <PerformRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Action>start</Action>
         <Definitions>
            <Definition xsi:type="Automation">
               <Client>
                  <ID>MY CLIENT ID HERE</ID>
               </Client>
               <ObjectID>MY OBJECTID HERE</ObjectID>
            </Definition>
         </Definitions>
      </PerformRequestMsg>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is the response I'm getting:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <soap:Header>
      <wsa:Action>PerformResponse</wsa:Action>
      <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:fceb9434-976c-4091-99d2-e171ffc67715</wsa:MessageID>
      <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:fbe32aae-7328-43a5-b64b-98d05c9d6d03</wsa:RelatesTo>
      <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
      <wsse:Security>
         <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-3eb52c64-7dc7-415c-a90f-c2ed316dbe6b">
            <wsu:Created>2021-01-22T17:06:47Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2021-01-22T17:11:47Z</wsu:Expires>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <PerformResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Results>
            <Result>
               <StatusCode>OK</StatusCode>
            </Result>
         </Results>
         <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
         <OverallStatusMessage/>
         <RequestID>REQUEST ID HERE</RequestID>
      </PerformResponseMsg>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

When I open SFMC automation studio, nothing is run- I've waited around 15 minutes now, and haven't seen anything come in. Both times that I've run it, the automation was sitting in Paused Status (4) and the automation is Active.

I'm wondering if there's a limit to the amount of times I can start an automation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The automation needs to have status "2" (ready) to be run via API. Maybe it was at first, but your first execution made it go into "paused" state for some reason.
To get it "ready", put in a schedule event, enter no time. The event will be grey.
Save the automation in this state.

If you now see the "run once" button activate, your automation should be ready to go.
You should see the execution instantly, 15 min. delays are nothing you need to be waiting for.

There is no limit to the number of times that an automation can be called when it's in the correct state.